# Scroll until animation is finished, then continue regular scrolling?

Tags: animation, scroll, fullpage.js

I'm trying to accomplish something like this: https://www.tomahawk.vc/

The page doesn't move until the animation is finished and then it keeps scrolling regularly.

How do I achieve something like that without having to scroll the website in the website, therefore taking me to the end of the page?

For further information:
On the site I'm working on I'm also using FullPage.js

Best,
Timo

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`beforeLeave` callback](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/docs/#beforeleave-origin-destination-direction-trigger).

Here's [an article](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/help/how-to-delay-scroll-wait-until-animation-is-done-on-fullpage-js/) explaining how to do it.

Example:

```js
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
    beforeLeave: function(origin, destination, direction, trigger){

        // prevents scroll until animation is done
        return isAnimationDone();
    }
});

// return true or false
function isAnimationDone(){
  // your logic here
}
```